# generate questionary from html to a xml

Tags: html, xml, nunit

I have a logistic web where there is a formulary to submit news package. I'm currently doing test runings on that website and I want to do some for that package formulary... The problem is that I want to do a lot of tests with diferent info in the formularys, and do that editing an xml is a bit tiresome.

I am looking for a tool that can generate a formulary about an html website (or with the .class object) with all the fields there are and where I can fill it and generate an automatic xml to do the tests.

My boss told me that it probably could do it with "wsdl" but i dont have any idea about that. Can you help me with any solution?

I'm working with .NET c#, and for the tests: gladio, watin and NUnit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *formulary to submit news package*, but if you are looking for sample data to do tests with, here are some sample data generators: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/test-sample-data-generators/

You can use the sample data to create and save xml files for your tests.

Also, `wsdl` is short for `Web Services Description Language`, which is on no use for your purpose.